# How to avoid loading ManyToOne objects during a select operation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
   int v1;
   int v2;

   @ManyToOne
   Bar bar;
}

Query query = EntityManager.createQuery("select foo from Foo");
```

The above query returns `Foo`(s), but also load(s) `bar` objects. How do I prevent loading of bar objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default many-to-one relation is eager. When lazy fetching is preferred, it can be done with following:

```
@ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

FetchType.LAZY is just hint to provider, according JPA 2.0 specification *Attributes with FetchType.LAZY may or may not have been loaded*. So it is not guaranteed to be lazy in all JPA implementations - in Hibernate it does work.